# How to repeat records from an ID for each following month if theres no records till a certain date?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query to calculate a rolling sum from a table with inventory values. It works fine, but we need to present this data in a historical graph, which shows how much inventory the company have.

I'm using Google BigQuery to perform the queries.

The problem is: the dataset is only updated if the material is used or bought. So if the last material movement was in jan/2021 saying that we have 20 unities of a material, on the graph will only show 20 unities in january, nothing on the following months (but we still have 20 unities in april in our inventory).

The query that I'm using is this:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (SELECT i.*,
             SUM(ESTOQUE_FINAL) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL ORDER BY CALDAY) as ESTOQUE,
             SUM(RMB_FINAL) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL ORDER BY CALDAY) as RMB,
             SUM(SAIDA) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL, MONTH_YEAR) as SAIDA_MES,
             EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(CALDAY)) AS DIAS_MES,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL, MONTH_YEAR ORDER BY CALDAY DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM bq_trusted.IINV_01_QINGDAO i
     ) i
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY MATERIAL, CALDAY
```

The result is:

| CALDAY | MATERIAL | ESTOQUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 25 |
| 2021-02-01 | A | 35 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 15 |
| 2021-02-01 | B | 70 |
| 2021-03-01 | B | 30 |
| 2021-04-01 | B | 40 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 40 |
| 2021-04-01 | C | 60 |

Note that we only have records from A in january and february, so the query that I need should have records in march and april equal to the last record from that material = 35. And C has a gap between january and april, so february and march should have 40 in ESTOQUE.

The ending result should be like this:

| CALDAY | MATERIAL | ESTOQUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 25 |
| 2021-02-01 | A | 35 |
| 2021-03-01 | A | 35 |
| 2021-04-01 | A | 35 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 15 |
| 2021-02-01 | B | 70 |
| 2021-03-01 | B | 30 |
| 2021-04-01 | B | 40 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 40 |
| 2021-02-01 | C | 40 |
| 2021-03-01 | C | 40 |
| 2021-04-01 | C | 60 |

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm almost there with Gordon's answer, but now the months that didn't have any records are coming as NULL. I added a new column in "i" to standardize my dates.

Using this query:

```
WITH i as (
      SELECT i.*
      FROM (SELECT i.*,
                   SUM(ESTOQUE_FINAL) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL ORDER BY CALDAY) as ESTOQUE,
                   SUM(RMB_FINAL) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL ORDER BY CALDAY) as RMB,
                   SUM(SAIDA) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL, MONTH_YEAR) as SAIDA_MES,
                   EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(CALDAY)) AS DIAS_MES,
                   LAST_DAY(CALDAY) AS DAY,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL, MONTH_YEAR ORDER BY CALDAY DESC) AS seqnum
            FROM bq_trusted.IINV_01_QINGDAO i
           ) i
      WHERE seqnum = 1
     )
SELECT m.MATERIAL, d.DAY,
       LAST_VALUE(i.ESTOQUE IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY m.MATERIAL ORDER BY i.DAY) as ESTOQUE
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MATERIAL FROM i) m CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT DAY FROM i) d LEFT JOIN
     i
     USING (MATERIAL, DAY)
ORDER BY MATERIAL, DAY;
```

I'm getting those results:

| DAY | MATERIAL | ESTOQUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | c | 25 |
| 2021-02-01 | C | null |
| 2021-03-01 | C | null |
| 2021-04-01 | C | 35 |
| 2021-05-01 | C | null |

And I need to be:

| DAY | MATERIAL | ESTOQUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | c | 25 |
| 2021-02-01 | C | 25 |
| 2021-03-01 | C | 25 |
| 2021-04-01 | C | 35 |
| 2021-05-01 | C | 35 |

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the rows using a `cross join` and then bring in the existing data:

```
WITH i as (
      SELECT i.*
      FROM (SELECT i.*,
                   SUM(ESTOQUE_FINAL) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL ORDER BY CALDAY) as ESTOQUE,
                   SUM(RMB_FINAL) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL ORDER BY CALDAY) as RMB,
                   SUM(SAIDA) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL, MONTH_YEAR) as SAIDA_MES,
                   EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(CALDAY)) AS DIAS_MES,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL, MONTH_YEAR ORDER BY CALDAY DESC) AS seqnum
            FROM bq_trusted.IINV_01_QINGDAO i
           ) i
      WHERE seqnum = 1
     )
SELECT m.MATERIAL, d.CALDAY,
       LAST_VALUE(i.ESTOQUE IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY m.MATERIAL ORDER BY i.CALDATE) as ESTOQUE
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MATERIAL FROM i) m CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT CALDAY FROM i) d LEFT JOIN
     i
     USING (MATERIAL, CALDAY)
ORDER BY MATERIAL, CALDAY;
```

You might have other ways of getting the list of materials or calendar days.  This uses the results from the inventory table.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it didn't work for me. This results in a table with ESTOQUE column as null.

Comment: Actually I did some tweaking and I think I'm almost there. There was a problem with CALDAY, so I used a LAST_DAY(CALDAY) on "i" to standardize the dates. Now it brings the results, but if there was no record in that month, it comes as NULL. I'm trying to copy the last non null value but can't get to work. I edited my post so you can see the changes I did

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to Gordon's answer -  you might be missing a date from your base table. For example, if you don't have any activity on 2021-03-01.

In that case you can leverage BigQuery's [GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_date_array) function to create an array of all the unique months between the first and last month in your data.

E.g.

```
SELECT m.MATERIAL, DAY,
       LAST_VALUE(i.ESTOQUE IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY m.MATERIAL ORDER BY DAY) as ESTOQUE
from
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY((SELECT MIN(CALDAY) from i), (SELECT MAX(CALDAY) from i), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as DAY
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT MATERIAL from i) as m
LEFT JOIN i
ON DAY =  i.CALDAY and m.MATERIAL = i.MATERIAL
order by 1, 2
```